# Redirection from subfolder to another

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I've a situation which I'm going nuts trying to fix.
I need to redirect anything in one folder to its new location at another folder.
Via htaccess, that is.

```
Site.com/event/ >>> Site.com/sub01/event/
```

**For a slightly more in-depth explanation of what I'd done, just in case it's needed:**

I had a wordpress installation (inside a subfolder resolving to the root of the domain).
I then moved that installation to a new folder as so:

```
Site.com/sub01 >>> Site.com/sub02
```

That second installation now resolves to the root with the original now resolving to its own folder.

I left behind one folder `/event/` with over 6,000 posts. Which ends up no longer located where it once was since it no longer resolves to the root. Follow?
Thus the reason behind needing the redirect. So that SE or actual person looking for that old address can still find it.

BTW, I've tried all sorts of code I'd found online...none of which worked. :(

====================

In response to Amit's question below,

Thanks for the reply Amit,

I've tried the following codes:

RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ /sub01/event/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ /sub01/event/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/event/ /sub01/event/ [R=301,L]

Mind you I've no clue what I'm doing in as far as this code's concerned.

Merely answers I found to other folks' similar questions.

As for what didn't work? Well, nothing changed at all except for simply, a page not found.

Thanks in advance to anyone with any input and insight.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and how it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally came across the answer.

It came through the use of Cpanel's Redirect Tool. I had no idea that solutions created that way are reflected through the htaccess found at the root of the domain.

But even that didn't work until I took the instructions inserted by Cpanel and moved them above all other instructions within the htaccess file.

Thanks folks for putting up with my ignorance in posting properly on this site.

Cheers! :)